# Survivor analysis when longest-term patient dies?

Tags: survival, censoring

I have been given some data that has date of admission, date of disposition, disposition (death or live discharge), and some biomarker levels. I would like to model this, but here is the rub:

The longest-staying patient died. All other patients left the study (were discharged from hospital) before that time period.

Is a conventional survival analysis appropriate for this?

Comment: why wouldn't it be?

Comment: In addition, this is the case where you can estimate mean life length without extrapolation using semiparametric method.

Comment: Their outcome for surviving patients is just censored.  All that might be affected is the accuracy of the estimated survival curve.